# What good are the Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, badges

There are two badges, [Tenacious](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/34/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/unsung-hero) that never have been awarded. And other than the [Illuminator](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/136/illuminator) badge that with enough diligence eventually can be awarded to someone willing to put in the hours, I'm not even sure it is possible to honestly achieve the easier one of the two, Tenacious, which says:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.

The entire site has just [136 accepted answers with 0 score](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A0%20isaccepted%3Ayes%20is%3Aanswer) out of 104K as of this writing, a bit more than 0.1%. It seems *extremely* unlikely anyone would get 20%+ such answers out of theirs unless they collaborated with someone to engineer just such an outcome.

Why do we still have these badges? Is this because we cannot retire badges that have no useful application?

Comment: Related on Meta SE: [Was the Unsung Hero a bad idea to implement?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56897/241919): "*these badges are more a consolation prize for those who don't already reap big Rep rewards.*" In addition to that, I doubt SE may retire some badges only on some sites.

Answer (score 28):

They're in our Q&A system for sites like Stack Overflow where it's much, much harder to get upvotes. SO for example has [65k Tenacious badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious) and [26k Unsung Hero badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero). After so little engagement a user might feel like giving up, but then a badge appears telling them they're doing something special still & please keep trying.

We just have them because we're using the same Q&A system and badges aren't defined on a site-specific basis. We don't need them because they don't reflect a problem we tend to experience, which is a good thing, but they'll still be around in our system for the sake of other sites that do need them.